# VC++ VS 2013, how to use (test) classes from another project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, googletest

I have a C++ (VS 2013) console application and I want to test it (using Google Test).

I created a separate project and added gtest include paths, etc. (for exanple using this tutorial http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/google_unit_test_gtest.php) and simple tests like this work fine:

```
TEST(MyTests, myTest1)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(2+2, 4);
}
```

But how to use classes from the main project? If I simply add the project dir to include paths then I can use "header-only" code but for classes with implementation in `.cpp` I get `unresolved external symbol` error.

Is there any better way than moving all classes to a library just to be able to test it?

Comment: _"Is there any better way than moving all classes to a library"_ No, you need to create a library for the classes under test.

Comment: Include required source files into your test project. Optionally, move test project files to the same folder where tested project files are (so including/excluding files would be easier). This works fine for small projects, but will quickly become a mess in a big multi-project solution.

Comment: And instead of "moving all classes to a library" think of it as "moving `main` function out into executable project". Things will get easier. ;)

Comment: Need to add that big project in this context mean little more than small project.

Comment: You can use these complete solution example created for Visual Studio 2015 : https://github.com/fuatcoskun/GoogleTestVS2015

Comment: Liitle offtopic remark, that does not concern Visual Studio but concern Qt. When we configuring Qt with .pro files, it is possible to write .pri files with list of project files. Than we include .pri files into project and into tests. This approuch is similar like @Drop suggest but does not become a mess in config of source files but become mountain of binary data on disk and make reason to work slowly. Analogically it is good only for small projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your project as library. And make little executable for startup. This solves many problems. There are many projects use this strategy. And one of them is Chromium. One another example is Perl language interpreter. Your project-library will be easy to link to tests.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this approach, looks like it is the easiest available. Although I think it is not as easy as it should be, like in other languages.:(